# Want requests.get to wait for redirection during some time

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I have experienced some problems concerning a fix period of time before the redirects to the other. I have already searched in StackOverflow for some way to make requests.get wait for let's say 7 seconds and get all history of redirects during this time, but nothing found.

The only thing I found that is near (even if far) to I want was timeout option of requests.

```
requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)
```

According to requests docs:

> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download

I think what I need is to give it this limit, to make it wait until 7 seconds, but couldn't even find where to change requests package.

Comment: What does it mean to *wait* for a redirection? `requests` isn't a browser... I suggest you read how an [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) works.

Comment: I know requests has the history of all urls it passes during redirecting, my problem is: the website waits 7 seconds before it starts to redirect.

Comment: *"the website waits 7 seconds before it starts to redirect."* Then it's not a 301/302 redirect, and `requests` won't follow it. It's either a [`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7; url=http://example.com/">`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), or Javascript.